# Kendo inline grid combobox TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Id' in null

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
grid._schemaMethod = {
    model: {
        id: 'Id',
        fields: {
            Id: { editable: false, databind:nullableValue: 'Id'},
            User: { defaultValue: { Id: '', UserFullName: '' } },
        }
    }
};

grid._columns.push(grid.GridColumn('Id', null, '200px', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, true));
grid._columns.push(grid.GridColumn('User', 'User', '200px', null, "#=User.UserFullName#", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, userNameEditor));
grid._columns.push(grid.GridColumn(null, '&nbsp;', '200px', { style: 'text-align:right' }, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ['edit', 'destroy']));
```

This is my grid

And this is my javascript function:

```
function userNameEditor(container, options) {

    var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '../Warehouse/SearchUser',
                dataType: "json"
            },
            success: function (e) {

            },
            error: function (e) {

            }
        }
    });
    var cmb = $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoComboBox({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField: "UserFullName",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            filter: "contains",
            minLength: 3,
            dataSource: gridDataSource,
            filtering: function (e) {

                var filter = e.filter;
                gridDataSource.read({ userSearchText: filter.value });
                //dataSource.filter({ userSearchText: filter.value });
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {

                var equipmentData = e.sender.dataSource.data();


                $.each(equipmentData, function (index, selectedEquipmentData) {
                    var dataItem = e.sender.dataSource.at(index);

                });
            },
            select: function (e) {

                this.refresh();
            },
            complete: function (e) {

            },
            error: function (e) {

            }
        }).data('kendoComboBox');
    cmb.refresh();

};
```

And my problem is that when I click update button my grid gives error  **TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Id' in null** why? I try .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "nullableValue: Id" }) but not worked and  https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-with-a-custom-dropdownlist-as-an-editor-not-showing-selected-values that link.  Can some body help me ?

Answer (score 0):

https://dojo.telerik.com/@bubblemaster/IYekeYoc go take this link.You taking this error because you make mistake databound in grid ...This solve your problem my problem solved